# Push different files to different Git remotes

Tags: git

I have a Git repository on GitHub and one for our server for production. The GitHub one is for other developers, therefore I would like that remote to have certain files which are needed for development. These files are not needed for production so I would not like them to be on the production remote.

A way to set this up would be to have separate .gitignore's though I'm aware this is not recommended. If not is there another viable solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to give specific advice without knowing more about the nature of the files you only need for development, but separate repositories for development and production is almost certainly not the approach you should take. You're practically guaranteeing that development and production will end up out of sync!

Speaking generally, if the files are third party dependencies most package managers have some way to manage development-only dependencies (and you probably want the directory they install into in .gitignore anyway). If they're configuration related, try to push the values out into environment variables or write the production values in during your deployment step.

Give [The Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/) a read, it's full of good information for managing these sorts of things.